# DataContractSerializer cannot read datatypes with empty namespace xmlns=""

Tags: xml, wcf, soap, xml-namespaces, datacontractserializer

Good day!
My wcf soap service should accept given xml messages which shold come from 3rd party service and which i can not change(in production).
I am using DataContractSerializer and have some trouble with deserializing of the message.

The message have this format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <Body>
    <newClaim xmlns="urn:CoeoService">
      <auth  xmlns="">
        <partnerId >49</partnerId>
        <sandbox>false</sandbox>
      </auth> 
      <person xmlns="">
        <id>123123</id>
        <dateOfBirth>2015-09-15</dateOfBirth>
      </person>
    </newClaim>
  </Body>
</Envelope>
```

However if i change the message(thnx SOAPUI) and delete the empty namespaces **xmlns=""** from auth and person types it works like a charm.

So it seems to be some mismatch in the namespaces i wrote in the code. 
But if i understand it right, the

```
 [DataContract(Namespace ="")]
```

attribute just deletes the namespace tag completely, so that i can't enforce DataContractSerializer to accept this one.

Is there any other method to achieve this and not to manualy parse the xml request?

My datacontract classes look like following

```
[assembly: ContractNamespace("",
   ClrNamespace = "CoeoService")]
namespace CoeoService
{
    [DataContract]
      public class Auth
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string partnerId;
        [DataMember]
        public bool sandbox;
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Person
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string id;
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime dateOfBirth;
    }

}
```

Thnx for any help,
best regards,
Alexander

Answer (score 1):

On my objects the namespace of each DataContract matches the xmlns namespace in my XML.

I think if you add:`Namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"`
to your DataContracts, then it should work.

Comment: The trick is `<person xmlns="">` and   `<id>123123</id>`   have empty namespace. It is tricky and seems cannot be achieved with this approach. But thnx anyway